# Unstable manifold of an unstable fixed point of a steepest descent iteration

Tags: dynamical-systems, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent, stability-theory

Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be differentiable $t:\mathbb R\to(0,\infty)$ be a "step size" function and $$\tau:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R\;,\;\;\;x\mapsto x-t(x)f'(x).$$ In the steepest descent method, we iterate $\tau$ to find a local minimum of $f$. Let's consider$^1$ $f(x)=x^2(x-2)^2$ so that $f'(x)=4x(x-1)(x-2)$.

Note that the fixed points of $\tau$ are precisely the critical points of $f$. In our case, $x_0:=0$, $x_1:=1$ and $x_2:=2$.

> How can we determine the [stable and unstable manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_manifold) of $x_1$?

It's clear to me that $x_1$ is unstable$^2$, since obviously there is a $\varepsilon>0$ with $f'(x)>0$ for all $x\in(x-\varepsilon,x)$ and $f'(x)<0$ for all $x\in(x,x+\varepsilon)$ so that the iteration "is moving away" from $x_1$ in different directions depending on whether we start close to the left or to the right of $x_1$.

---

$^1$ $f$: [image] $f'$:[image]

$^2$ Recall that a set $A$ is *stable* if for every neighborhood $N$ of $A$, there is a neighborhood $U$ of $A$ such that $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N_0}\tau^n(U)\subseteq N$. A point $x$ is stable if $\{x\}$ is stable.

Comment: Why not make your question self-contained and define *stable manifold* and *unstable manifold*? Wikipedia is not all that static.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Yes, I know. The reason is that I've noticed that the terms *stable manifold* and *unstable manifold* are not used consistently in the literature (they often differ in subtle ways), which is why I wanted to leave some room for adjusting these notions appropriately.